# How to make an angular component reusable? (Angular 2+)

Tags: html, angular

I made an input box for an IP Address with Port. This input box is made of 5 inputs box within a div. This is a basic example.

```html
<div class="form-inline" style="display: inline-block">
  <input required name="block1" class="form-control" #block1="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="ipBlock1">.
  <input required name="block2" class="form-control" #block2="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="ipBlock2">.
  <input required name="block3" class="form-control" #block3="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="ipBlock3">.
  <input required name="block4" class="form-control" #block4="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="ipBlock4">:
  <input required name="block5" class="form-control" #block5="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="ipBlock5">
</div>
```

In ip-address-input.component.ts file I have:

```
@Input() ipProtocol
@Output() ipAddressCreated: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<{ipAddress: string}>();
ipBlock1: string;
ipBlock2: string;
//some logic like string concatenation (ipBlock1 + '.' + ipBlock2 + '.' + ...)
```

In app.component.html:

```
<ip-address-input [ipProtocol]="dhcpRangeStart"></ip-address-input>
<ip-address-input [ipProtocol]="dhcpRangeStop"></ip-address-input>
```

But when I check for example for the first IP it returns the last entered IP. How I can make this component reusable (make multiple instances of it)

Image with the actual IP Input box:

[image]

Comment: how do you get the value from this component?

Comment: can you provide the implementation of the ip-address-input component? also show how you get the value from the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a few controls similar to yours by leveraging `ControlValueAccessor` and `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` from angular forms. Basically, these provide you with a pattern to build your own custom and reusable form controls.

Below is an example code but you can also follow [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/) to get your component built.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

const IP_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => IpInputComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'ip-address-input',
  providers: [IP_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
  templateUrl: './ip-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ip-input.component.css']
})
export class IpInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

ipBlock1: string;
ipBlock2: string;
ipBlock3: string;
ipBlock4: string;
ipBlock5: string;

    disabled: boolean;
    onChange: Function; 
    onTouched: Function; 

    get value(): string {
        return ipBlock1 + '.' + ipBlock2 + '.' + ipBlock3 + '.' + ipBlock4 + ':' + ipBlock5;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.onChange = (_: any) => {};
        this.onTouched = () => {};
        this.disabled = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        if(obj) {
            let arr = obj.split('.');

            this.ipBlock1 = arr[0];
            this.ipBlock2 = arr[1];
            this.ipBlock3 = arr[2];
            this.ipBlock4 = arr[3].split(':')[0];
            this.ipBlock5 = arr[3].split(':')[1];
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="form-inline" style="display: inline-block">
  <input required class="form-control" type="number" [ngModel]="ipBlock1" />. 
  <input required class="form-control" type="number" [ngModel]="ipBlock2" />.
  <input required class="form-control" type="number" [ngModel]="ipBlock3" />.
  <input required class="form-control" type="number" [ngModel]="ipBlock4" />:
  <input required class="form-control" type="number" [ngModel]="ipBlock5" />
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<ip-address-input formControlName="ipAddress" (value)="ipAddress.value"></ip-address-input>
```

HTH

Comment: Beat me to it by 2 mins...here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-54rrua) demo

Comment: Thank you for your example.